# IF statement which finds multiple words

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Updated Question:

Someone left an answer with a CountIF (I think the comment was removed) the count if works; thank you! :)  ....When I copy this formula to the next column it doesn't seem to work,  the line below is the count if formula
                                                                                                                                                                  `=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4,"*"&J2&"*")>0,"found","none")`

I want the If to select text values in sheet 2 column A1:A4

---

Original Question:

I want to create an IF statement which finds more than one value I have tried adding another IF but this doesn't seem to work and i am not sure why.

Below is the formula i have so far.

```
   =IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1, I2), 0), "found", "none")
```

This searches in Sheet 2 what is in Column A row 1 if this is found in Column I2 of the Sheet 1.

I want the IF statement to also find what is in Sheet2!$A$2, Sheet2!$A$3 and Sheet2!$A$4

Answer (score 1):

You will want to sum all of the four results and see if the result is greater than zero. If it is, then at least one of the [SEARCH functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) returned true.

The array¹ formula is,

```
=IF(SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4, I2))), "found", "none")
```

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula.</sub>

Comment: It doesn't need changing. The problem is that you are confusing the numeric return of a [SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) with the text it is searching for. I gave you clickable links for more information. Use them. Try the formula out. Use Evaluate Formula if you don't understand something.